# Include a DynamicResource binding in a ComboBox's ItemStringFormat?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking for a way to bind a DynamicResource into a ComboBox's ItemStringFormat.

For example I want to do something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemStringFormat="{}{DynamicResource String_Prefix}: {0}" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a markup extension inside a format string. However, if the format string in the resource contains the `"{0}"` placeholder, you can just do that:

```
<ComboBox ItemStringFormat="{DynamicResource String_Prefix}" />
```